# How to proporly make CORS request with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors

I am attempting to access a REST API at a different domain, so I am aware that I need to make a CORS request to do this on account of the same-origin policy. Everyone recommends that I look at [this article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) for instruction, but when I apply the same process I seem to get this error:

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.culpa.info/professors/gold_nuggets. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

This is the code I am using to make the request, and print the incoming text once received:

```
let url = "http://api.culpa.info/professors/gold_nuggets";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET',url,true);

xhr.onload = function() {
    var text = xhr.responseText;
    console.log(text);
};

xhr.send();
```

Does anybbody know what the issue is? Or what the next step I should take is?

Note: I am using Google Chrome. Also this URL doesn't support JSONP.

Comment: Had you done a web search for that error you would have come up with thousands of results

Comment: @charlietfl I did. They all tell me to use this same article but the code I was instructed to use doesn't get rid of the error.

Comment: Use a proxy on a server you control or a third party service, unless you control the server code on domain you are trying to reach

Comment: CORS  has to be enabled by the **server**.

Answer (score 0):

In php you should call header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); or insted * your allowed domain.